# Dynamically Creating Pages on jQuery-mobile using javascript that reads JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

Basically I'm trying to make my jquery-mobile application as dynamic as possible so therefore it takes as much variables as possible from a JSON file. I've set up a javascript method that takes in the JSON file, has a series of link buttons with different names and they link to pages which I'm trying to create dynamically and display information on via collapsible elements. 
I'll concede that it's a faily ambitious method but it is valid unerrored javascript but I feel that jquery-mobile just won't be able to handle it. 
If someone could take a look over my code and tell me if it is possible to do and if so what am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="Page1">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <a href="info.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info"> Info </a>
        <h2>Skin &amp; Soft Tissue</h2>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Page1_Content">
        <p class="infotext"><b>Clinical Condition:</b></p>
        <div id="texts"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function () {
              var info = "";
              var dpages = "";
              var pageno = 1;
              var imp = "Json/empirical.json";
              $.getJSON(imp, function (data) {
                  $.each(data.tcontent, function (i, item) {
                      if (item.Name == 'Skin and Soft Tissue Infections') {
                          var search = item.Variations;
                          $.each(search, function (j, subitem) {

                              info += '<a href="#Paged' + pageno + '" data-role="button" data-mini="true">' + subitem.condition + '</a>';

                              dpages += '<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="Paged' + pageno + '"> <div data-role="header" data-theme="c"> <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back"> Back </a> <a href="info.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data transition="flip" data-icon="info"> Info </a> <h2>Skin &amp; Soft Tissue</h2> </div> <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Paged ' + pageno + '_Content"> <div data-role="collapsible-set"><div data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d"> <h3> Likely Organisms </h3> <p class="guidelinetext"> ' + subitem.organisms + ' </p></div></div> <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c"> <h2>(c) Darragh O Connor </h2></div> </div></div>';
                              pageno++;
                          });
                      }
                      $("#texts").empty().append(info).collapsibleset();
                      $("#pages").empty().append(dpages);
                  });
              });
          });       
        </script>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
        <h2>(c) Darragh O'Connor </h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pages"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pages should be appended to `body` = `$.mobile.pageContainer`. `$.mobile.pageContainer.append(dpages);`

Comment: Omar is correct, add pages to BODY. You can assign a class to the pages and then easily remove previous dynamic pages $(".classname").remove(). Here is a similar fiddle from an earlier question: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nn5Rw/2/

Comment: Yes Omar. That works. Thanks! I tried to then change the page to data-rel="dialog" but that messed up the format for the collapsibles. I presume this is just because JQM can't handle collapsibles inside a dialog?

Comment: `data-role=dialog` instead of `data-role=page` if you want to create dialog. `data-rel=dialog` is used on link to call a dialog.

Comment: I had put `data-rel="dialog"` in the link for the page. I put in `data-role="dialog"` too and the formatting stayed the same. It seems that the collapsible is on a separate page to the dialog (although it initially looks the same because of the white backgrounds) and it drops over the dialog page.

Comment: I just noticed that you're using JQM 1.4. Note that dialog will is deprecated and will be removed in 1.5. Also,there is no `data-role=dialog`,it should be `data-role=page` and `data-dialog=true`.

Comment: What should I do to remedy this? Would be be a bad option changing to 1.3 or is there a new implementation in 1.5 coming in to counter the removal of dialog?